# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wp_nav_menu_remove_menu_item_has_children_class()

Tags: php, wordpress, arguments, fatal-error

I need help figuring this out. I don't know what to do to fix this, Requesting help.

The site was moved from `a1pestcontrolco.net` to `a1pestcontrolco.com`. Same host provider. They say they can't help me.

> **PHP Fatal error:** Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wp_nav_menu_remove_menu_item_has_children_class(), 1 passed in /home/shatterp/public_html/a1pestcontrolco.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324 and at least 2 expected in /home/shatterp/public_html/a1pestcontrolco.net/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php:659
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home/shatterp/public_html/a1pestcontrolco.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): wp_nav_menu_remove_menu_item_has_children_class(Array)
>
> #1 /home/shatterp/public_html/a1pestcontrolco.net/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)
>
> #2 /home/shatterp/public_html/a1pestcontrolco.net/wp-content/themes/anona/framework/common/atp_generator.php(584): apply_filters('nav_menu_css_cl...', Array)
>
> #3 /home/shatterp/public_html/a1pestcontrolco.net/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php(147): description_walker->start_el('', Object(WP_Post), 0, Object(stdClass))
>
> #4 /home/shatterp/public_html/a1pestcontrolco.net/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php(247): Walker->display_element(Ob in /home/shatterp/public_html/a1pestcontrolco.net/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 659

Based on this thread, it looks like it's related to code that may be deprecated due to a change in PHP versions.

I tried to change the PHP version in .htaccess, but it rendered the site even more useless. I was hoping it would fix the errors. But I just don't know what to do and am seeking help :(

Comment: Are you sure that changing the php version from htacces is working?? Did you tried to print a php info to check of is really change the php version?

Comment: When i changed the PHP version, the site displays even worse, and when i try to view it after changing it, it downloads site info instead of letting anyone view it, so i changed it back :(

Comment: The issue is being caused by your WordPress theme, specifically in `/wp-content/themes/anona/framework/common/atp_generator.php`, line 584. Form the stack trace it seems your theme is programmatically manipulating some CSS classes from one of your navigation menus. That's all we can tell you at the moment since we don't have access to your code.

Comment: @cabrerahector, where can i send you the code?

Comment: Edit your question and add all the relevant code there (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so we can help.

Comment: @cabrerahectoryeah i just tried doint that for the last 2 hours and it wont add the code... keeps finding errors. im getting frustrated :( it would be sooooo much easier if i could just copy and past... but i cant... it want indents like everywhere...and it's not enough...then it breaks the code completely...can i just email something.that just seems simpler to me